# Computer shutdown while downloading mojave, and now there is not enough space to download

Tags: macos, mojave, shutdown

I was downloading MacOS Mojave and most of the way through, my computer shut down. Before I started downloading I had about 10GB of space on my hard disk. Now I about 6GB. How do I get rid of whatever temporary files are using all the space?

Comment: you are pushing the limits. First keep 10% of SSD free. Second, move or remove some stuff, install mojave then clean disk.

Comment: You have a Time Machine backup, right?  *Right??*

Comment: What version OS are you running?  Was it the full installer/install assistant of 6 GB you were trying to download, or some combo update? PS. 10 GB is not enough for either, an update (ca. 14.5 GB), or full installer (ca. 19 GB).

Comment: I am running High Sierra. What I want is the installer to update to Mojave. I was downloading it from the app store. I would assume that an update wouldn't use too much more space than the system files already take up (about 36GB out of 50GB).

Comment: Partial installer file is probably in your Applications folder, sporting the most recent "date added" or "modified" value. Trash it, and begin the install from the start. It would not hurt at all to first offload a bunch of whatever docs are eating all the space on your SSD. You are running far too close to the limit for my comfort.

Answer (score 1):

First empty your trash (just in case). Then open Finder and hit Command + F. You should now get an empty Finder window with the option to add search parameters:

[image: image of Finder search criteria]

The first one, `Kind is Any` is already there for you. At the right side of this row click the "+" icon to add a parameter. You can see the ones I chose are:

- File Size is greater than 4 GB
- System files are included
- Content modified is today

You may have to go into the "other" section of the dropdown menu to find "System files". In sum, this Finder search locates all files, including system files, that are greater than four gigabytes in size *and* modified today. Tweak the parameters if you don't believe you've found what you are looking for, and carefully review any matches so you don't delete crucial system files.

Comment: Nothing is returned when I put that in, even without the modified bit. Trash is definitely empty.